# ¿Cómo obtengo en Java 8 usando lambdas los elementos repetidos y a la vez en forma ordenada? ej : Juan 3 Pablo 2 Andres 1

Tags: java, lambda, stream

Estoy trabajando sobre este código, básicamente  sobre una lista de Strings obtengo los elementos y los debería mostrar desde el que aparece mas veces hasta el que aparece una sola vez, por ejemplo:

Juan 3
Andres 2
Marcelo 1

```
        List<String> listnames = new ArrayList<>();

        listnames.add("Juan");
        listnames.add("Juan");
        listnames.add("Juan");
        listnames.add("Andres");
        listnames.add("Andres");
        listnames.add("Marcelo");

        listnames.forEach(System.out::println);

        Map<String, Long> result =
                listnames.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                Collectors.counting()));


        System.out.println(result);
```

La salida genera lo siguiente : {Andres=2, Marcelo=1, Juan=3}
Pero lo que necesitaría es obtenerlo de esta forma : {Juan=3, Andres=2, Marcelo=1 }

Alguien me podría explicar como generar un sort?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibas por buen camino, pero te faltaban un par de pasos.

En primer lugar, para ordenar las entradas con la API de Streams tendrás que utilizar el `Set` que te devuelve `Map::entrySet` (**Fíjate que como paso intermedio hemos creado un Set**):

```
data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream() // Obtenemos las entradas del Map y las pasamos por un Stream
```

Después tendrás que ordenarlas, comparando los valores y no las claves:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // Ordenamos comparando por valores (las ocurrencias de cada nombre)
                                          // Aquí se compara por el orden natural de Long, es decir que 1 va antes que 2
```

Y por último tendrás que guardarlas en un `Map`, pero para que se respete el orden que has conseguido tendrá que ser un `LinkedHashMap`:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,                 // Función para obtener la clave
        Map.Entry::getValue,               // Función para obtener el valor
        (existing, incoming) -> existing,  // Función para saber qué hacer si se encuentra dos claves iguales a la hora de insertar
        LinkedHashMap::new));              // Función generadora que determina qué implementación de Map utilizar, en este caso LinkedHashMap es la que queremos
```

En tu caso querías que los numeros mayores fueran antes, por lo que en el momento de ordenar tendrás que suplir tu propio comparador:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.getValue(), b.getValue()) * -1) // comparador inverso
```

Answer (score 0):

por las respuestas anteriores, yo la manera que encontré de solucionarlo fue la siguiente :

Dado este código :

```
Map<String, Long> result = listNames.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Finalmente lo ordené de como lo necesitaba de la siguiente manera :

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Long >> orderResult = result.entrySet().stream().sorted((a,b) -> Long.compare(b.getValue(),a.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```